# Javascript onbeforeunload cancel

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

Is there a way to cancel the javascript event `onbeforeunload`, and just have it execute a function and return to the page?

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    //execute some logic
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Sure.  You can write your own web browser that has this feature.

Comment: I think you forgot to put quotation marks around "feature."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No.  You cannot cancel this event.  All you can do is have it return a string.  That will make the browser ask the user if they want to leave.

Just imagine if you *could* block this event!  You could make a site that the user could **never close**!  Just imagine all the popups you could make.  There's no way browsers are going to allow this.

Comment: But why do the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) say that this event is cancelable?

Comment: .. Oh I guess they mean that the user can cancel it via the confirm box... but you can't cancel it programmatically

Answer (score 3):

No. You can't stop people leaving a page if they want to.

Answer (score -2):

Yes. You can do this by making it null.

window.onbeforeunload = null;